# Javascript - Get a corresponding object between two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays:

First array:

```
const dummyJSON = [
    {
      id: 1,
      sponsor_date: '2020-08-16T22:45:03.154Z'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sponsor_date: '2020-09-16T22:45:03.154Z'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sponsor_date: '2020-09-01T22:45:03.154Z'
    }
  ]
```

Second array:

```
const validated = [ true, false, false ]
```

And I wanted to get the object (dummyJSON.id) when the corresponding (validated) array item is true.

Basically, if the first item in the validate [0] array has a value of "true", then I would like to have the corresponding [0] item's id value in the dummyJSON array.

Comment: Are you looking for all of the objects that have a `true` validated value? What's the desired output (an array of ID's? one ID?)

Comment: @CollinD Yes! My desired output is to have an array of ids.

Comment: @Taplar. I just like it ahahah. srry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to get array of validated ids.

It will basically loop over every element and if the index of currently iterated object corresponds to the truthy value inside `validated` with the very same index, the object's `id` will be pushed to the result.

```js
const dummyJSON = [
    { id: 1, sponsor_date: '2020-08-16T22:45:03.154Z' },
    { id: 2, sponsor_date: '2020-09-16T22:45:03.154Z' },
    { id: 3, sponsor_date: '2020-09-01T22:45:03.154Z' }
];

const validated = [true, false, false];

const validatedIds = dummyJSON
  .reduce((s, { id }, i) => (validated[i] ? s.push(id) : s, s), []);

console.log(validatedIds);
```

Comment: Great solution, might be worth adding a bit of explanation, the `reduce` function can be a bit confusing if you've never used it before, especially combined with arg destructuring, one-letter variable names and a ternary lol

Comment: @CollinD Thank you, updated the answer with some details.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is just to get the validated items, use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const valid = dummyJSON.filter((item, index) => validated[index]);
```

If you just want the ids, add a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call:

```js
const valid = dummyJSON.filter((item, index) => validated[index]);
const ids = valid.map(x => x.id);
```

This could be done in a single line if you prefer, by chaining the map call:

```js
const ids = dummyJSON.filter((item, index) => validated[index]).map(x => x.id);
```

```js
const dummyJSON = [
    { id: 1, sponsor_date: '2020-08-16T22:45:03.154Z' },
    { id: 2, sponsor_date: '2020-09-16T22:45:03.154Z' },
    { id: 3, sponsor_date: '2020-09-01T22:45:03.154Z' }
];

const validated = [ true, false, false ];

// source objects
console.log(dummyJSON.filter((_, index) => validated[index]));

// just the ids
console.log(dummyJSON.filter((_, index) => validated[index]).map(x => x.id));
```

Comment: I believe the asker wants only ids to be returned, not whole objects.

Comment: Noted. Updated to add a map call to get the ids.

Answer (score 0):

No need for reduce, filter can do that just as well and faster :

```
const validated = [ true, false, false ]
const dummyJSON = [
    {
      id: 1,
      sponsor_date: '2020-08-16T22:45:03.154Z'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sponsor_date: '2020-09-16T22:45:03.154Z'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sponsor_date: '2020-09-01T22:45:03.154Z'
    }
  ]
// To get all validated objects from dummy JSON
const validatedJSON = dummyJSON.filter((obj, index) => validated[index])
// To extract just the ID's
const validatedJSONIds = validatedJSON.map(json => json.id)
```